# Private access? Java

Tags: java, class, private

I have a private access error to do with the variable "totalFloat". However I have been referencing and using methods from the same class without this problem.

Is there a general way to get around a private access error in this case?

```
public static void writeHtmlFile() {
  double contentsChangeDraw;

  String ChangeDrawer = "ChangeFloat.html";
  try {
    PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(ChangeDrawer); 
    contentsChangeDraw=cd.getTotalFloat(totalFloat); 

    // totalFloat has private access in ChangeDrawer, which means I am
    // unable to use the method to calculate the array that needs to be written  

    outputStream.println(contentsChangeDraw); 
    outputStream.close(); 
    System.out.println("The contents of the ChangeDrawer have been written to a file");
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();      
  }       
}
```

Comment: is totalFloat non-static

Comment: what is cd? is it an object of type ChangeDrawer?

Comment: oh! as a private double. woops! that solves the problem. Thankyou!!

Comment: We need more context. We don't know which class this method is part of. We don't know how and where totalFloat is defined. We don't know the exact error message you get.

Comment: Unless you're programming for android, it's better probably better practice if you leave it as private and create a getter method for it instead.

Comment: @GenericJon Why should programming for android change that definition of good/bad practice? ;)

Comment: @brimborium Because android advise against it for performance reasons. See: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/performance.html#internal_get_set

Comment: @GenericJon Thanks, learned something today. Although this post does not advise against private members. It advises against the usage of get/set **within** the class itself, independent of the variable being private/public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet `totalFloat` has a declaration like this:

```
private int totalFloat; // or double, or boolean, or something else
```

You can not access it from a static method because it's a member variable. Make it

```
private static int totalFloat; // or double, or boolean, or something else
```

to access it (or change your method `writeHtmlFile()` to not being static).